# Deriving the motion equation for a minimally-coupled scalar field in general relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

From the following Lagrangian

$$
L = \sqrt{-g} (R+\epsilon\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi)
$$
I'm getting the motion equation (for the field $g_{\mu\nu}$ and vaccum)as:

$$
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=\epsilon\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi
$$

However, in the articles I'm reading, they get:

$$
R_{\mu\nu}=\epsilon\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi
$$

that is, exactly the same as me but with $R=0$. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a conservation of indices question. How are there two free indices on the LHS, while there are no free indices on the RHS?

Comment: Kevin, you are right, I messed with the indexes writing it down here. In the last two equations we have $\epsilon \partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi$

Comment: Qmechanic, here's an article with those equations:  http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604055 (equation 1 and 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you have for the stress-energy tensor (the right hand side of the Einstein-equation) for the scalar field is incorrect. We have

$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R = T^\phi_{\mu\nu}$$

where

$$T^\phi_{\mu\nu} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta [\sqrt{-g}\epsilon g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\phi\partial_\beta\phi]}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} =  -\epsilon \partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi + \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\epsilon(\partial^\alpha\phi\partial_\alpha\phi)$$

If we now take the trace of the Einstein-equation we find $R = -\epsilon(\partial^\alpha\phi\partial_\alpha\phi)$ which we can substitute back into the Einstein equation to find

$$R_{\mu\nu} = T^\phi_{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R = -\epsilon \partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi$$

Comment: I'm sorry Winther, but as you can see in here:

http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0604055
(equation 1 and 2)

i've posted the correct lagrangian (I also corrected some indexes now).

Comment: Thanks Winther, you are really correct with this. However, in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9804064 he defines (1), make a conformal transformation to get to (2) (WITH $\sqrt{-g}$) getting to the motion equation in (4) as I have stated.

Comment: @EdisonCesar Well I do get the same result here (up to a sign). I may have made a sign-error somewhere (or using a different sign-convention for the Ricci tensor). I will look into it and update the answer as soon as I get time.

Comment: @EdisonCesar I found the sign error (which was in the definition of $T_{\mu\nu}$) and have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I'm not understanding one thing, if I'm working in vacuum, why do I have a $T_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: @EdisonCesar The scalar field carries energy. If you don't want to use the abstraction with the stress energy tensor then just take the variation of the whole action and you still get the same Einstein equation out of it.